# Is it possible to execute the formula [Column1] +[column2]/10000 in dynamic sql for Square Brackets

Tags: sql

I tried executing some formula in Dynamic SQL concept in the format enclosed in square brackets like `([15] + [20]) /10000...` which got failed.

But when I tried with `((15)+(20))/10000` it worked.

Is it possible to use square brackets in dynamic SQL calculation?

Comment: Tag dbms used!!! (Seems to be a product specific issue.)

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot use [] is you are using values. If you are using columns instead of values its possible.

Whatever inside the square bracket SQL Server consider it as a column name.
So it will give you 'Msg 207' Invalid column name.

But you can use square barckets inside the wildcart like this

```
LIKE 'WC[[]R]S123456' 
or

LIKE 'WC\[R]S123456' ESCAPE '\'
```